# How to avoid typing alphabets in date picker field?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

How to avoid typing alphabets in date picker field?

I'am using bsDatePicker

I used type="number", But i am getting this warning and i couldn't select date

```
"The specified value "02/03/2020" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?"
```

Comment: use regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use keypress event preventDefault() method to cancels the keypress event.

**Try this:**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
    <input (keypress)="$event.preventDefault()"
     type="text"
           placeholder="Datepicker"
           class="form-control"
           bsDatepicker>
  </div>
```

or Use readonly attribute

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
    <input readonly
     type="text"
           placeholder="Datepicker"
           class="form-control"
           bsDatepicker>
  </div>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sk6bck)

Comment: Thanks..It works fine!!!, But i couldn't delete the selected date

Comment: Then try keypress event

Comment: keypress event will not work on all event check this for more info:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Comment: Fixed my issue!! Thank-you!!

Answer (score 1):

You dont define to type of number , you can just define like :

```
public taskDate = new Date();
```

in your .ts file

Define below code in .html file

```
 <input type="text" readOnly class="form-contr bsDatepicker
                         placeholder="Select Date" [(ngModel)]="taskDate"
                         [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }">
```

**Dont forget to add readOnly tag in your input text.**

Comment: Thanks..It works fine!!!, But i couldn't delete the selected date

Comment: i used readonly so cannot use delete functionality but you can used  a validation error when user enter an alphabhet in text field.

Comment: But tihs prevents you from actually typing anything. OP wanted to avoid typing letters.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a pattern in your input field instead of `type="number"`

Eg: `<input type="text" pattern="(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/\d{4}">`

Also, if you are assigning the value to this input from a date picker, make this input field `readonly`

Answer (score 0):

Just use type date to solve your problem:

```
<input type="date"
        [minDate]="minDate"
        [maxDate]="maxDate"
        bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="yourDateValue">
```

[Here is an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: The specified value "02/24/2020" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd". --> getting this warning

Answer (score -1):

You can try this keyup event on your input like this:

```
<input onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" >
```